# Is it possible connect to server when app is suspended?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I wanna check server if there is new  message count I will set my badgeNumber. When applicationdidenterBackground I can connect server and check it with timer repeat and repeat. But I wanna do that if app is killed  too(not at background).

So shortly, is it possible work with background tasks when app suspended?

Comment: Just use [push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html).

Comment: I know push notifications. But i don't wanna push if every time count changed. Another way ?

Comment: "*I **don't wanna** push*"... why not?? That's the only way you'll be able to reliably communicate with your software in the non-running state. Not considering push as an option because you "don't wanna" is exhausting your only reliable and realistic option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use background tasks in iOS just for 10 minutes, except if your app is registered as VoIP app.

Comment: Can you provide a source for both these claims?

Comment: do you have any article, link etc ? @Slavco

Comment: For background tasks that last for 10 mins, yes i have source because I've tried that, but I've never registered an VoIP app.

Comment: For background tasks that last for 10 mins, yes i have source because I've tried that, but I've never registered an VoIP app. Just follow this link for http://blog.dkaminsky.info/2013/01/27/keep-your-ios-app-running-in-background-forever/     Thank you @esqew

Answer (score 0):

As others have observed, push notifications are designed for this exact purpose. It puts no load on the client, which makes for the best battery life and resource utilisation.

Having said that, in iOS 7 there is a new multitasking feature called "[background fetch](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html)." This will run a specific method in your app occasionally. In this you could check the status on the server and update the badge number. You don't get to choose the timing and it's more resource intensive, but it would work.